# How to over ride the default scroll up behavior of Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have implemented Jquery Mobile 1.4.2 along with Jquery 1.11.0   .

I have small bug . That is when the pages are loaded it scrolls up automatically .

For example if I am on a list view And I have scrolled down till half of the page and I refresh the page . Then it goes back to the top.

Is it a default behavior? or its a bug . I am not able to find out anything related with this

If its a Default Behavior  Then something like this we can do but its just an assumption

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
//apply overrides here
})
```

Refrence : [**Article**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/)

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks & Regards

Comment: I think this is more of a browser feature than a jQuery bug. Some browsers remember the position, some ignore it.

Comment: @Spokey I bumped into this string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393696/scrollto-gets-overridden-when-using-jquery-mobile .... Looks Like it was the Jquery Mobile only

Comment: I see in the comments that it still did not work in some browsers making it a browser compatibility issue. This seems to have been already asked alot of times. An example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353766/saving-scroll-postion-with-jquery-mobile-1-3-list-view

Comment: @Spokey your right bro . in the link that I provided they are forcing the browser to load from 100px . Which is not right bcoz might refresh the page when he is gone to bottom of the page or anywhere else . And yes this has been asked number of times . I feel bad that till now I was thinking this as double reload problem and was searching the wrong keyword

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21989837/1771795